# Meteor: how to group results in template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an app where user can check in at different datetime. My goal is then to show who was there at different dates.

Something like that:

> 11/05 : Mat, Lisa, Andrew
>
> 14/05 : Lisa
>
> etc.

I took a look at $groupby aggregation but it seems really heavy for my simple usage.
I can also loop on the db.find().fetch() but I feel like I would lost reactiveness.

I managed to make it works with a simple template helper:

```
resultDate = null;

Template.result.helpers({
    date: function(){
        var date = moment(this.datetime).endOf("day").fromNow();

        if(date == resultDate)
            return false;

        resultDate = date;

        return date;
    }
}
```

But as you can see, it's not really the classy way and everything collapse if I need to call {{date}} twice for example.

I have looked for a proper solution for hours and found nothing. Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this client side with your collection and without losing reactivity.

The key issue is to turn a reactive datasource (the collection) into an array of objects that mirrors the desired output of dates with the names of people checking in. 
This array would look something like:

```
[
  {date: '2015-05-11', names: ['Mat', 'Lisa', 'Andrew']},
  {date: '2015-05-14', names: ['Lisa']},
]
```

I'm assuming you collection is called Checkin and has 2 fields in each document, `date` and `name`.

Your collection is a reactive datasource. You can get notified about changes to the collection with `observeChanges`. 
By triggering the added, changed and removed events, you can rebuild the array with check-ins per day. The events all call `rebuildCheckinPerDay` that will build the actual array.
The array is then saved in a ReactiveVar `checkinPerDateVar` each time it was rebuild. And because a ReactiveVar is also a reactive datasource, the template helper `checkinPerDate` gets rerun each time the reactiveVar is changed.

Building the array is done by several underscorejs functions. First, the collection is sorted by date and fetched in an array, then grouped by date (time was removed by `.endOf('day')`) and then mapped to the final structure. Because `_.groupBy` returns items as {id, name, date} you have to use `_.pluck` to extract the name.

For converting dates and a convenient template helper to format dates, I used [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). To actually run this example you would have to include packages `momentjs:moment` and `reactive-var`.
In the example the full date is displayed. But you easily transform that to the `moment(this.datetime).endOf("day").fromNow()` if you like.

**Full example:**

**check-in.html.**

```
<template name="checkinPerDate">
    {{#each checkinPerDate}}
        <div>
            {{formatDate date}} - {{names}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**check-in.js.**

```
Template.registerHelper('formatDate', function(date) {
    return moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
});

// Reactive variable to hold the array with names per check-in day
var checkinPerDateVar = new ReactiveVar([]);

// Build the array with check-ins per day that mirror the final view in the template
var rebuildCheckinPerDay = function() {
    var checkinPerDateArray = _.map(
        _.groupBy(Checkin.find({}, {sort: {date : 1}}).fetch(), function(item) {
            return moment(item.date).endOf('day');
        }), function(dateItem, date) {
            return {date: date, names: _.pluck(dateItem, 'name')};
        });
    checkinPerDateVar.set(checkinPerDateArray);
}

Template.checkinPerDate.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('checkin', function() {
        var cursor = Checkin.find();
        var handle = cursor.observeChanges({
            added: function (id, checkin) {
                console.log('added ', id, JSON.stringify(checkin));
                rebuildCheckinPerDay();
            },
            changed: function (id, checkin) {
                console.log('changed ', id, JSON.stringify(checkin));
                rebuildCheckinPerDay();
            },
            removed: function (id) {
                console.log('removed ', id);
                rebuildCheckinPerDay();
            }
        });
    });
});

Template.checkinPerDate.helpers({
    // This helper function is reactive because of the use of reactive variable checkinPerDateVar.
    // It gets rerun each time the variable was changed
    checkinPerDate: function () {
        var checkinPerDateArray = checkinPerDateVar.get();
        return checkinPerDateArray;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jos for your answer but it still looks pretty heavy to me for my simple need which is more related to HTML formating than object manipulation. I think your answer is great for complex treatment over the request but in my case, I only need to display the date of date sorted records without repeating when it is the same day.

So, I worked out my initial helper function and I think I have found a better way to do that:

```
var resultDateVar = [];

Template.result.helpers({
    date: function(){
        if(!resultDateVar[this._id]){
            var date = moment(this.datetime).endOf("day").fromNow();

            resultDateVar[this._id] = (resultDateVar.last == date)? false : date;
            resultDateVar.last = date;
        }

        return resultDateVar[this._id]
    }
});
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: Okay, no problem. I learned a few things myself while trying to get it done.